# The view account.views.user_login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, html, django

**Cannot register or login account.views didn't return http response**

```
# accounts/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from account.forms import RegistrationForm, UserLoginForm

def register(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(username=username, email=email, password=password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('home')  # Redirect to your home page
        else:
         context['registration_form'] = form
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def user_login(request):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")
    
    if request.POST:
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                user_login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()

        context['login_form'] = form
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

I tried to register users but its telling me that my account.views is not returning an Http response but the users account will be updated in my django admin and if try to log in it still show the same error

Comment: Might be wrong in your urls.py, what's your settings there?

Answer (score 1):

There's two paths to get that bug.

1. request.method == "POST" and not form.is_valid()
2. request.method == "POST" and user.authenticate() fails

The solution is to "outdent" the last line (`return render(request, ...`) so that it becomes the catch-all.  (This is done properly in your `register` function).